# injecting ajax using ScriptInjector GWT

Tags: javascript, ajax, gwt

I want to inject ajax (to retreive data from a web service) into my html code that has been generated by GWT.

I tried injecting the cdn of jQuery and my script using ScriptInjector.

here's how I injected the cdn to the head of my html:

```
Element head = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("head").getItem(0);
ScriptElement sce = Document.get().createScriptElement();
sce.setSrc("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js");
head.appendChild(sce);
```

that worked fine, I've inspected my page and it has been added to the head.

And here's how I tried to inject the script to get data from my web service:

```
ScriptInjector.fromString(" $.ajax({\n" +
"  dataType: \"json\",\n" +
"  url: \"http://localhost/geoTrackerTest.php?id=15\",\n" +
"  data: \"data\",\n" +
"  success: function(data){\n"
+"   console.log(\"success\");" +
"    document.getElementById(\"frigoTempAjax\").innerHTML = data[0].frigo_temperature;\n" +
"  }\n" +
"});").inject();
```

I expect to get a success message on the console and to get a value in the div that has the specified Id but I'm getting the following error:

`ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ScriptInjector` will by default inject into the hidden iframe where your GWT code runs; you need to tell it to inject into your page instead, where the jQuery script lives.

```
ScriptInjector.fromString(…).setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
```

But in this case it might be better to replace the jQuery code with equivalent GWT code (using `com.google.gwt.http` or `com.google.gwt.xhr`)

Comment: Okay I understand, seems logical, but do you have any idea how to inject that script into my page?

Comment: And for using `com.google.gwt.http` I guess that needs to run in the server side while I just want my code to run on the client side. am I wrong?

Comment: Added example using ScriptInjector. Also, com.google.gwt.http is GWT, it runs on client side!

Comment: I've tried that, it's still not working and it's showing on console  the following error: `TypeError: $.ajax is not a function`

Comment: Well, I fixed the ajax problem by injecting the cdn in another class (you can say the parent class or the main somehow), still the value I wanna change is not inserted yet, when I inspected my page, I can see the GET request provided by my web service but `console.log(\"success\");` and `document.getElementById(\"frigoTempAjax\").innerHTML = data[0].frigo_temperature;` seems not to work at all. the console isn't showing no errors yet not printing what I logged and the value of my div isn't changing. how can I fix that?